# How do I group following dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a timeseries of discharge data. I want to select certain peak events. 
What I did was calculate a treshold, and made a table with the exceeding periods:

```
%create the treshold value
select min(dummie.value) from (select top 5 percent value from timevalues where id = 
(select id from source where type = 'observation') as dummie) as treshold

%view every time where the value is higher then treshold
select name, time, value from timevalue, catchment
where timevalue.sourceID = source.id 
and where source.id = catchment.sourceID
and where value >= treshold.value 
as exceed_table
```

Now I want all the periods that the values are above this treshold, and then count how many they are. is there a way to remove all the data where it's one timestep further then the one before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by copying the exceed_table, adding one timestep to it and then substracting the exceed_table and the copied one.